# PHP & Mysqli - Selecting one column as an string and not as an array

Tags: php, database, select, mysqli

I want to know if there is a way to select a one detail (id of someone) from the DB without making it an array, using PHP and MySQLI.

Comment: Can you elaborate? MySQLI select queries return a result set, which must be iterated to get attributes from each row returned.

Comment: Do you want to return one or more rows? Isn't this just a question of writing a good query?

Comment: I meant to say selecting only one detail(id of someone).

Answer (score 3):

You can have the results put into an object, then select the column.
E.g. to select the column `name` from a query, you could use

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1'");
echo $query->fetch_object()->name;
```

instead of using the more common

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1'");
$data = $query->fetch_array();
echo $data['name'];
```

If the query returns multiple rows, you could just put this into a while query like with an array set of results.

Comment: I meant to say selecting only one detail(id of someone).

Comment: #jocabEid $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1'"); is selecting one column and due to mentioning where id="1" it is selecting one value

Answer (score 1):

Use group_concat():

```
$query = 'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ", ") FROM tblUser';

if($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_object();
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

This will return 1 column (name) with 1 value (a comma separated list/string of each userid in the table)

Example table:

```
tblUser
+--------+-----------+
| userid | name      |
+--------+-----------+
|  3     |    Joe    | 
|  4     |    Mike   |
|  5     |    Sharon | 
+--------+-----------+
```

Using the above query will return:

```
+----------------------+
| name                 |
+----------------------+
| `Joe, Mike, Sharon`  |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: I think he wants something like when he fetch result set, to get one string instead of an array

Comment: I meant to say selecting only one detail(id of someone).

Comment: Like my updated example above?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Since databases deal with columns and rows nearly all API's at least have a representation using lists (arrays)

But you can easily get a single result relatively quick:

```
// Query results a single result
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT somecolumns FROM table WHERE somecondition");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0]; // The desired field
```

Comment: I meant to say selecting only one detail(id of someone).

Answer (score 0):

```
function getColumn($field,$table){

  $db=new mysqli("server","user","pass","db");

  $rs=$db->query("select $field from $table");

  return $rs;
}

//then call it as follows:

$r=getColumn("fieldName","tableName");

while($col=$r->fetch_array()){

 echo "$col[0]";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getColumn($field,$table){

$db=new mysqli("server","user","pass","db");

$rs=$db->query("select $field from $table");

$str="";

while($row=fetch_array()){
$str.=$row[0]."<br/>";
}

return $str;

}

//then call it as follows:

$col=getColumn("fieldName","tableName");

echo $col;

}
```